# filtering out values in a multi-dimensional array in php

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a situation where I have two arrays and I use one array(A) to determine which elements of the second array(B) I need to use. Since I will be combing B multiple times and each time I will not need the previously used elements I have written a function that I call sift_array.

```
function sift_array(&$array, $key, $value){
   foreach($array as $element){
      if($element[$key] == $value){$temp[] = $element;}
      else{$temp2[] = $element;}
   }
   $array = $temp2;
   return $temp;
}
```

I am curious if there is a **faster** way to perform this function.

Here is an example of how I use this function.

In my web app users can set up a 'bot' to perform an action so many times while they are away/logged off. I have a program that will run periodically to operate the bots. The bots can not run the same action if it was the last bot to do so.

The bots array has 3 key elements     : account_id, action_id, job_id
The job array has 1 key element      : job_id.

I pass in the bots array then for the $key I pass 'job_id' and for the $value I pass the job id I am working with, say job 1.

```
$runTheseBots = sift_array($bots, 'job_id', 1);
executeBots($runTheseBots);
```

*This will have a faster execution time because all the bots that deal with job 1 are already handled.*

```
$runTheseBots = sift_array($bots, 'job_id', 2); 
executeBots($runTheseBots);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to implement this, but I'll just comment on how you've done it:

```
function sift_array(&$array, $key, $value){
   foreach($array as $i => $element){
      if($element[$key] == $value){
        $temp[] = $element;
        unset($array[$i]);
      }      
   }
   return $temp;
}
```

Here we are saving memory and time (well, maybe not time... benchmark to see) by not making a copy of `$array`. Simply delete the element after you move it to the new array.

Again, I don't claim this to be the best way of doing it... just a way to optimize what you've already done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will benchmark this version to see if it is faster. Cheers.

Comment: You're suggestion has saved a lot of memory and a noticeable amount of time as the number of bots increases as well as the number of jobs in my simple benchmark test. Thanks again.

Comment: If you're dealing with huge arrays, it may even be faster to call `executeBot($element)` inside `sift_array` and not ever build `$temp`. Of course it makes the function less general purpose, but sometimes speed is of more concern. Also, you may want to consider solutions that let you process one record at a time without ever building any large arrays up front. I don't really understand what you are doing well enough to offer any suggestions on that front.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a fold approach:

```
function sift($array, $key, $value) {
    return array_reduce($array, function ($a, $elem) use ($key, $value) {
        $elem[$key] == $value ? $a[0] = $elem : $a[1] = $elem;
    }, array());
}

$bots = sift($array, 'job_id', 2);
executeBots($bots[0]);
```

This IMO mostly improves the "interface" by eliminating the pass-by-reference + return and returning a "grouped" array. PHP *may* be able to optimize this better internally and hence it *may* be more efficient, but I don't know in how far that is really the case. Might be worth a try though.

---

OK, a bit of testing shows that it's actually a lot *slower*. But, if you're only filtering the bots you're interested in and discard the rest, `array_filter` can give a boost. If you're discarding anyway though, completely unsetting the unneeded values is the fastest by far:

```
$bots = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
    $bots = array('job_id' => mt_rand(1, 100));
}

function sift_reduce($array, $key, $value) {
    return array_reduce($array, function ($a, $elem) use ($key, $value) {
        $elem[$key] == $value ? $a[0] = $elem : $a[1] = $elem;
    }, array());
}

function sift_filter($array, $key, $value) {
    return array_filter($array, function ($elem) use ($key, $value) { return $elem[$key] == $value; });
}

function sift_unset(&$array, $key, $value) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $elem) {
        if ($elem[$key] != $value) {
            unset($array[$k]);
        }
    }
}

function sift_array(&$array, $key, $value){
   foreach($array as $element){
      if($element[$key] == $value){$temp[] = $element;}
      else{$temp2[] = $element;}
   }
   $array = $temp2;
   return $temp;
}

$start = microtime(true);
$sifted = sift_reduce($bots, 'job_id', 5);
echo "reduce:  " . (microtime(true) - $start) * 1000 . "\n";

$start = microtime(true);
$sifted = sift_filter($bots, 'job_id', 5);
echo "filter:  " . (microtime(true) - $start) * 1000 . "\n";

$botsCopy = $bots;
$start = microtime(true);
sift_unset($botsCopy, 'job_id', 5);
echo "unset:   " . (microtime(true) - $start) * 1000 . "\n";

$start = microtime(true);
$sifted = sift_array($bots, 'job_id', 5);
echo "array:   " . (microtime(true) - $start) * 1000 . "\n";
```

Gives:

```
reduce:  0.072002410888672
filter:  0.013828277587891
unset:   0.0088214874267578
array:   0.016927719116211
```

Comment: I am definitely willing to try this out. I'm interested in see how this solution compares to passing a reference and return. Thank you for your time. Cheers.

Comment: I like the speed of the unset, but I need to preserve the unused bots in an array and process them with the next job. By unsetting the used bots from the original array as I find them I have been able to speed things up, only marginally. For now that improvement can get me by while I find my next slowest piece of code. I greatly appreciate your help and everyone else's.

Answer (score 0):

A better option would be something called a "Bucket sort".

This is the quickest option for sorting, if there is a relatively small number of 'buckets'.

In this case, each job_id is a 'bucket'.

You only want to be sifting the array once. For each element, you place it in an appropriate bucket, depending on the job_id, (one bucket per job_id).

That way the array is only sorted once, and accessing all elements for each job consumes zero extra processing.

If optimising is absolutely critical, you could have two or more sort functions. Selection of the sort algorithm is done at run time based on the number of buckets and elements that need to be dealt with.

Comment: I honestly have not thought about sifting the array once into "buckets" and then working from there. I will give this a try. As far as optimizing I have not run into any problems as of yet but I've recently doubled my registered accounts and have seen at times bots falling behind, and would like to streamline this segment of my code  being that it is the slowest part at the moment. Thank you for your time. Cheers.